# Create element from external js-script and insert into html

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a widget. Something like google-adsense blocks, so I need to call the same script from different places of the page. Is it possible to create an element in external js-script and insert it to the place where I called the script?

I do this:

```
<div><script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></div>
<div><script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></div>
```

Loader.js:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'inner-div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

And I have:

```
<div><script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></div>
<div><script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></div>
<div class="inner-div"></div>
<div class="inner-div"></div>
```

But I'd like to get this result:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js">
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js">
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution. Find current script tag:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
  loadScript('loader.js', function () {
    loader().init({script: script});
  });
</script>
</div>
```

loadScript function:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

then in loader.js:

```
init: function(args) {
...
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'inner-div');
args.script.parentNode.appendChild(div);
...
}
```